# Does SQL Server backup corrupted pages?

Tags: sql-server

If my db has some corrupted page, SQL Server copy those page normally without warning about it? it's necessary to run `RESTORE VERIFYONLY` to find any corruption in backup?

Comment: If the corruption is in your database's MDF files, then it's corrupt there.  SQL Will happily back that up into a BAK file for you.  RESTORE VERIFYONLY does not do any DBCC checks that would catch page corruption, it only makes sure that the backup is readable.  If you have corruption in your database, you NEED to use DBCC CHECKDB to find it.  You can potentially use a backup to restore a clean page (YMMV) if you have a backup from before the corruption occurred and can tolerate potential data loss.  Good luck.